# Sharepoint Rest Query to get files last modified between given timestamp

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, modified, last-modified-date

I have a query in SP where I get the list of files  added/ modified after a given timestamp. This works for me:

```
_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='myurl/myfolder')/Files?$filter=TimeLastModified gt datetime'2018-5-20T09:59:32'
```

Is there a way that I can get the list of files at a given folder, between two timestamps? 
Like all files added/updated where **TimeLastModified gt startTime and TImeLastModified less than end time**

Thanks in advance. Seems documentation is quite limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple filter in the current api Url to achieve this.
Try like this,

```
_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='myurl/myfolder')/Files?$filter=TimeLastModified gt datetime'2018-5-20T09:59:32' and TimeLastModified lt datetime'2018-5-20T10:59:32'
```